# Control music on MacBook and iPhone using VoiceOver (iPod version)

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, headphones, remote-control, music.app

I used to have an iPod nano, but the headphones that came with it broke and the newer headphone is not compatible with it, so I stopped using it. I now listen to music primarily using my MacBook and iPhone, but I still miss the way I can control the iPod (switch playlists) using headphone only, especially when I'm tired and don't want to open my eyes, unlock the phone, and select the playlist I want.

I'm currently using PowerBeats 3. All other commands like forward/back and quick forward works, with the only exception being playlist selection holding the middle button, which wakes Siri instead. Is there a way to emulate iPod voiceover to control music playback (specifically playlist selection) on my MacBook and iPhone using external headphones?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can activate Siri already. Just ask her to switch to a certain playlist.

Comment: I will try that. But sometimes I can't remember the playlist name and sometimes there are other people around that I don't want to disturb. So having iPod-like voiceover control is still very convenient.

Comment: How does any of that differ between siri and voicecontrol? Wouldn't you need to tell voice-control the exact same thing?

Comment: No. For iPod, when you long-press the middle button, the current song title will be read, then all playlist title will be read. When the playlist I want is read, I can select it by clicking on the middle button. This is sometimes more convenient than Siri.